# Flask - How to send variables to different routes without redirecting?

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have made two routes in Flask. I want to send variables to a route from another route but I don't want it to get redirect to it the route.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    name = 'Hello'
    return redirect(url_for('a', name=name)

@app.route('/<name>')
def a(name):
    return name
```

What I want is that my index should not redirect to `'a'` route. `'a'` route should work only whenever I type it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `index()` and `a()` are really just functions. You can call them directly; so in `index()` you can call `a(name='Hello')` and return the result of that call:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    name = 'Hello'
    return a(name=name)

@app.route('/<name>')
def a(name):
    return name
```

You can also register multiple URLs for a single view function, including using defaults for paths that don't have variables in them. You then don't have to call anything yourself:

```
@app.route('/<name>')
@app.route('/', defaults={'name': 'Hello'})
def a(name):
    return name
```

When the `/` URL is matched, `a(name='Hello')` is called, because the `defaults` map sets `name`.

For more information, see the [*URL Route Registrations* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#url-route-registrations) of the Flask API documentation.